# pvlib for read surfrad dataset has issue

Tags: pvlib

In order to access [SURFRAD](https://gml.noaa.gov/grad/surfrad/) irradiance data, I am running the following python command using the [pvlib library](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/):

```
import pvlib
data, meta = pvlib.iotools.read_surfrad(filename, map_variables=True)
```

I used URL for surfrad solar irradiance data as "https://gml.noaa.gov/aftp/data/radiation/surfrad/Boulder_CO/2020/". However, when applied this to the filename parameter, it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename argument passed to the pvlib SURFRAD reader function can either be a local path or a link to a specific file on the SURFRAD FTP server.

To get data from the Boulder station for January 1st 2020, the correct filename would be:

```
filename = 'ftp://aftp.cmdl.noaa.gov/data/radiation/surfrad/Boulder_CO/2020/tbl20001.dat'
```

Comment: How to specify the time range on a monthly basis. For example, If I want to download data for April 2020

Comment: Unfortunately, the get_surfrad function is currently limited to only retrieving data for one day at a time. Thus, currently, you have to loop over the individual files. We would happily accept a pull request to add a start/end keyword to allow for retrieving multiple days of data.